# Angular2 carrying data stored in a variable from app.component.ts(parent component) to other components

Tags: angular

Question(1):-Want to carry `"results"` data from `app.component.ts` to `abc.component.ts`, `bcd.component.ts`, `cde.component.ts` and use in function like done below.
  How to do that?

Question(2):-Here, getting `"results"` data in console.log.

but Getting Error in  `alert(this.loadedCharacter )` as `undefined`?

### app.component.ts

```
    import { Component,OnInit, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { Http } from "@angular/http";
    import { SingletonService } from './commons/data-singleton.service';
    import { JsonDataService } from "app/services/json-data/json-data.service";
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
      providers:[]
    })
    export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
      loadedCharacter: {};
loadedCharacter1: {};
      clientJson1: {
        "aoId": string;
        "viewBys": string[];
        "viewIds": string[];
        "globalViewbys": string[];
        "globalViewIds": string[];
        "dimensions": string[];
        "meassures": string[];
        "meassureIds": string[];
        "aggregation": string[];
        "globalInFilters": any;
        "globalNotInFilters": {
        };
        "localInFilters": {
        };
        "localNotInFilters": {
        };
        "drillDownFilters": {
        };
        "drillAcrossFilters": {
        };
      };
      clientJson: {
        "aoId": string;
        "viewBys": string[];
        "viewIds": string[];
        "globalViewbys": string[];
        "globalViewIds": string[];
        "dimensions": string[];
        "meassures": string[];
        "meassureIds": string[];
        "aggregation": string[];
        "globalInFilters": any;
        "globalNotInFilters": {
        };
        "localInFilters": {
        };
        "localNotInFilters": {
        };
        "drillDownFilters": {
        };
        "drillAcrossFilters": {
        };
      };
      data1: Observable<any>;
      data: Observable<any>;


      // SolrService
      public aoId: string[]
      public viewbys: string[] = ["brand"];  //Given by user  "Brand", "Category", "State" , "Region" , "city" , "Payment Method"
      public viewbysId: string[] = ["", "615128", "614847"];
      public dimensions: string[] = ["615228"];
      public measuresDefault: string[] = ["sales", "netsales"]; //Given by user
      public measures: string[] = ["sales", "netsales"]; //Given by user
      public measuresId: string[] = ["616275", "616283", "616279", "616648", "616295"];
      public aggregation = ["SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM", "SUM"];
      public globalInFilters: any = {};
      public globalNotInFilters = {};
      public localInFilters = {};
      public localNotInFilters = {};
      public drillDownFilters = {};
      public drillAcrossFilters = {};

      public elementIdsMap: any = { "615228": "Brand", "615128": "Category", "614847": "state" };

    private url ="http://183.82./Pvice/sovice"; //Global Server
      constructor(private router: Router, private http: Http, public jsonDataService: JsonDataService) {
      }

      ngOnInit() {
         this.clientJson = {
          "aoId": "M_AO_918",
          "viewBys": this.viewbys,
          "viewIds": this.viewbysId,
          "globalViewbys": ["brand", "uscity", "usstate"],
          "globalViewIds": ["615228", "615128", "614847"],
          "dimensions": this.dimensions,
          "meassures": this.measuresDefault,
          "meassureIds": this.measuresId,
          "aggregation": this.aggregation,
          "globalInFilters": this.globalInFilters,
          "globalNotInFilters": this.globalNotInFilters,
          "localInFilters": this.localInFilters,
          "localNotInFilters": this.localNotInFilters,
          "drillDownFilters": this.drillDownFilters,
          "drillAcrossFilters": this.drillAcrossFilters
        };

    this.clientJson1 ={
     "aoId": "M_AO_918",
          "viewBys": ["usstate"],
          "viewIds": this.viewbysId,
          "globalViewbys": ["brand", "uscity", "usstate"],
          "globalViewIds": ["615228", "615128", "614847"],
          "dimensions": this.dimensions,
          "meassures": this.measuresDefault,
          "meassureIds": this.measuresId,
          "aggregation": this.aggregation,
          "globalInFilters": this.globalInFilters,
          "globalNotInFilters": this.globalNotInFilters,
          "localInFilters": this.localInFilters,
          "localNotInFilters": this.localNotInFilters,
          "drillDownFilters": this.drillDownFilters,
          "drillAcrossFilters": this.drillAcrossFilters
    }

     this.data = this.http.post(this.url,this.clientJson).map(res => res.json());
        this.data1 = this.http.post(this.url,this.clientJson1).map(res => res.json());
           Observable.forkJoin([this.data , this.data1 ]).subscribe(results => {
          //results here
          this.loadedCharacter1  = results[1];
          this.loadedCharacter = results[0];
          console.log("results"+JSON.stringify(results[1]));
          console.log("results"+JSON.stringify(results[0]));
          // return results;
        });
         alert(this.loadedCharacter );
      }
    }
```

### abc.component.ts

```
 initData(){

//how to get loadedCharacter from `app.component.ts` here, and then pass it into buildabcchart() as below;


let jsonData = loadedCharacter;   // loadedCharacter: {}; from app.component.ts
buildabcchart(jsonData );
}

buildabcchart(jsonData ){
/*--------------*/
}
```

Comment: this.loadedCharacter is undefined because you are calling alert outside of the asynchronous task (forkJoin().subscribe). It is being called before the http requests finish. If you move it into the subscribe (and after you assign this.loadedCharacter) it should alert the data

Comment: Thanks @LLai, I got it. Please suggest something for question1 above.

Comment: Also a sidenote, I believe you do not need the brackets in your forkJoin() method. Observable.forkJoin([this.data, this.data1]); it should just be Observable.forkJoin(this.data, this.data1) per the rxjs documentation https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/forkjoin.md

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question 1:

Here is a plunkr that demonstrates passing data from a parent component to child components https://plnkr.co/edit/dsnJShi87UUseFLVGscH?p=preview

So this uses the input binding to pass data from the parent to child.

```
// parent html
<child-component [someInput]="loadedCharacter"></child-component>

// child ts
export class ChildComponent{
    @Input() someInput; // someInput can be used throughout the child component
}
```

Now when loadedCharacter is defined in your parent.ts it is passed to the child through the "someInput" input binding.

For the second part of your question, "using the passed in data in a function", you can use the ngOnChanges lifecycle hook. In your child component you can add something like

```
// child ts
export class ChildComponent implements OnChanges {
    @Input() someInput; // someInput can be used throughout the child component


    ngOnChanges(){
        // do something with someInput here. This lifecycle hook is fired every time 1 or multiple input bindings are changed
    }
}
```

Resource on input binding: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#pass-data-from-parent-to-child-with-input-binding

Resource on ngOnChanges lifecycle hook: https://angular.io/api/core/OnChanges

---

Question 2

this.loadedCharacter is undefined because you are calling alert outside of the asynchronous task (forkJoin().subscribe). It is being called before the http requests finish. If you move it into the subscribe (and after you assign this.loadedCharacter) it should alert the data

Comment: Thanks @LLai. Hope it might help.

Comment: @ManzerAhmad I hope it helps! I've added ngOnChanges to the plunkr

Comment: Thanks @LLai, I have updated plunk, Can you do something like, if metadata is "brand" get brand data from "data.json"  for pie component and if metadata is "state" get state data from "data.json" for line component.

Comment: @ManzerAhmad can you post the plunkr link?

Comment: here is the  link : https://plnkr.co/edit/ilWquIKDjXfC1VgMZab0?p=preview

Comment: @ManzerAhmad I am confused what you are looking for. You are wanting a reusable observable method? https://plnkr.co/edit/yfsYfZrMbH1YBcVyzNPg?p=preview This plunkr would make 2 api requests though